# How do I create a Neo4J multi-graph using gds.version() 1.7.2?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, knowledge-graph

I want to project a subgraph  that contains multiple nodes and relationship types. In gds 2.0 there is this (https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/graph-project/):

```
CALL gds.graph.project(
  'personsAndBooks',    
  ['Person', 'Book'],   
  ['KNOWS', 'READ']     
)
YIELD
  graphName AS graph, nodeProjection, nodeCount AS nodes, relationshipCount AS rels
```

I want to do something similar, using gds 1.7.2 `gds.graph.create.cypher`, but the node and edge selection only take strings not lists. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `gds.graph.create` procedure ([doc](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/1.8/graph-create/#graph-create-native-syntax)), which is the equivalent of `project` in previous versions of GDS:

```
CALL gds.graph.create(
  'personsAndBooks',    
  ['Person', 'Book'],   
  ['KNOWS', 'READ']     
)
YIELD
  graphName AS graph, nodeProjection, nodeCount AS nodes, relationshipCount AS rels
```

This is the so called "native projection", as opposed to "Cypher projection" which is performed by the `.cypher` procedure you mention, which expect a Cypher query as parameter, hence the string.